# I'm adding pictures directly (not as floats) in the tabular environment, I get a very odd space above

Tags: tables, spacing, includegraphics

I'm working on inserting pictures alongside an enumeration. I add them directly, not as float, I don't need a caption. Now, I get a very odd space before the table/picture.
[image: The page of my output]

Now, I worked with \vspace{-1 cm} and more, which helps a bit, but after a certain value, it completely messes it up, This example here is without negative vspace.
The code which generates this is

```
    \newpage

\subsubsection{1. Mountain Pose: Stand Upright}

\begin{tabular}{p{1.9cm} p{9.6cm}}
  \raisebox{-1.1\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{SS_Mountain}} &                                                                     
\begin{itemize}
\item Put your feet with firm pressure on the ground. Pay attention that your toes don't claw into the ground.
\item Lock your knees. By doing this, your legs will get stretched (exception: people with knee problems: leave your knees slightly bend).
\item Turn the tailbone down and forward, tense up the muscles of the pelvic floor and the sphincter of your anus. The pelvis lifts up.
\item Tense up the abs.
\item Widen and lift your chest.
\item Bend your shoulder blades backwards and lower them.
\item Feel into the posture, from the feet up the the crown.
\item Put your hands into a salutation pose and focus on the area of your heart.
\item Slightly lower your head.
\item Let your breath flow slowly and calmly.
\item Interlock your thumbs and exhale deeply.
\end{itemize}
  
\end{tabular}
```

I tried to make a minimum working example, put I failed to reproduce the problem, it looks as it should:

```
\documentclass[makeidx]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{1. Mountain Pose: Stand Upright}

\begin{tabular}{p{1.9cm} p{9.6cm}}
  \raisebox{-1.1\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{SS_Mountain}} &                                                                     
\begin{itemize}
\item Put your feet with firm pressure on the ground. Pay attention that your toes don't claw into the ground.
\item Lock your knees. By doing this, your legs will get stretched (exception: people with knee problems: leave your knees slightly bend).

\end{itemize}
  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which generates me the following perfect output:
[image]

Now adding for instance a \vspace{-5cm} before the tabular part, then suddenly makes everything be too high up. It's almost as if there's a thing which toggles that space and if you go above a certain threshold negative space it's like that space was never there.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, I'm at a loss and couldn't find anything about that problem.

My best regards
Rapha

Comment: Is what you want a bullet list with a graphic next to it, as if it was in a separate column? If so, you (ab)use a table for layout purposes? Is that your point?

Comment: you are using book do flushbottom so tex is justifying page content to the bottom presumably at top of next page is something big. avoiding this problem is why images are usually floats. use `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Hi @David Carlisle, thank you so much for your help. The solution worked and the other post really explained it well. Very much appreciated
Yes, that is what I am doing. I didn't find a better solution so far.